# Mod Rewrite - How to get folders and parameters?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters, get

I've searched the web and stack-overflow for this, and got a few answers. Oddly enough, they just don't work and I can't figure out why!

I have an index.php file that receives the URL folders and parameters. For example:
example.com/folder1/folder2/?param=a&param2=b
I am echoing them inside the index.php like this:

```
<?php
     echo "<pre>";
     echo "Folders: "; print_r($_GET['folders']);
     echo "<br>";
     echo "Parameters: "; print_r($_GET['parameters']);
     echo "</pre>";
?>
```

And this is the output that I get:

```
 Folders: folder1/folder2/
 Parameters: folder1/folder2/
```

This is the htaccess that I use:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?folders=$0&parameters=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

How do I achieve an output like this:

```
 Folders: folder1/folder2/
 Parameters: a/b/
```

(or inside an array. Anything that would let me work with later)

Answer (score 0):

I got it!
Damn. **It was so obvious!**

.htaccess has nothing to do with it. The parameters will appear inside index.php using $_GET['some_parameter']

You can see all parameters using:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo "All parameters: ";
print_r($_GET);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get all the parameters using $_REQUEST:

```
echo 'All Parameters:';
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo "</pre>";
```

$_REQUEST returns all parameters which are send using both methods GET AND POST.